# How to wait for websockets to close gracefully on application shutdown?

Tags: quarkus, java-websocket

We have the following issue:

Preconditions:

- Quarkus application received WebSockets connections
- Quarkus application is running in a pod (Kubernetes)
- The WebSockets connection is going through layers of 2 load balancers (elb, nginx) but we made sure that we increased the idle connection timeout (300s)
- Websocket server must wait for connection closes before the shutdown
- The client for the server doesn't have a reconnect mechanism
- we have a shutdown hook to wait for the WebSockets sessions closes

Scenario when the pod is about to close:

- the application received a SIGTERM
- Sometimes some connections (but not all) closes with Reason GOING_AWAY (indicates that an endpoint is "going away", such as a server going down or a browser having navigated away from a page)

The shutdown hook:

```
 void onStop(@Observes final ShutdownEvent ev) {
    long numActiveSessions = getActiveSessions();
    while (numActiveSessions > 0) {
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(waitforfinished);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return;
        }
        numActiveSessions = getActiveSessions();
    }
}
```

There is a better way to do this? Why we received the GOING_AWAY reason? Are quarkus closing the WebSockets when it received a SIGTERM?

Update:
example project: https://github.com/pedrolopix/quarkus-websockets-example

Comment: After investigating, I did a shutdown hook with sun.misc.SignalHandler to catch the SIGTERM signal and it started working like it was supposed to, demo here: https://github.com/pedrolopix/quarkus-websockets-example/pull/2/files